# Javascript TimeStamp

Tags: javascript

How to know that user is in my page for more than 20 minutes using java script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a javascript variable to store the timestamp at the time of loading the page. You can find the time elapsed since that time at any time after that using a javascript function either invoked periodically or on a desired event.

Comment: Will it work ?? var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

Answer (score 3):

you can use setTimeout call,

```
function after20min() {
  alert("Still here?");
}

setTimeout(after20min, 1200000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout('pingServer()', 20*60*1000);
```

Now you only need to write `pingServer()` function.

Answer (score 2):

In the `onload` event, invoke `setTimeout` with that amount of time, and pass it a function that does whatever computation is done when the user has been on the page for that amount of time. Note, though, that just because the page is open that long doesn't mean anyone is looking at it; it would be a good idea to make sure that there are some sort of events triggering periodically on the page.